# JavaScript: why is that overriding setTimeout on window object would cause Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I wanted to override the default `setTimout` with my own version. so I did this

```js
window.setTimeout = () => console.log("lol");
setTimeout();
```

turns out it caused a stack overflow problem in codesandbox. here is the live demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-wildflower-g0u1x?file=/src/index.js

If I tried it in Chrome directly, it would not throw an error but it prints out `lol` randomly so it still doesn't work right.

Not sure what when wrong here. I know generally we shouldn't modify the global object i.e. `window`.

Comment: *"but it prints out lol randomly so it still "* Did you do that on a website that uses `setTimeout` by any chance?

Comment: Did you take a look at the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Is there any chance that codesandbox.io did overwrite `console.log`, and use `setTimeout` in their implementation?